# PointerMoved event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows store app that draws an image under the system's cursor. I capture all the cursor movements using:

```
var window = Window.Current .Content;
window .AddHandler(PointerMovedEvent, new PointerEventHandler (window_PointerMoved), true);
```

And this is working fine if I use my mouse to move the cursor.

However, I have another application - a desktop application -, that changes the position of the system's cursor. I'm using this method to set the position of the cursor programatically:

```
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

However, when the cursor is moved programatically, the PointerMovedEvent on the store app does not fire!
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I could not use System.Runtime .InteropServices on Windows store apps, but it is allowed. Therefore, I've managed to achieve the desired behavior by having a thread that actively checks the cursor's current position using:

```
[ DllImport("user32.dll" )]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works!